# Using reserved words in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reserved-words

I have a fairly large and complicated set of applications that were written in an older version of VC++.

There are methods in several of the lower-level classes (used everywhere) named "export()".

In more recent versions of C++, "export" is a reserved word. Reserved, but never used, and apparently it never will be.

Is there something I can do, in VC++ 2015, to allow this code to compile, without having to rename the methods?

Comment: *"and apparently it never will be"* - Don't count on it. Modules look like they will come to C++20.

Comment: Add a preprocessor definition like `export=my_export` to the project settings. Since you probably have many projects, you may want to batch process project files with some kind of tool. This is a dirty hack, I would not recommend it and suggest renaming anyway. But if you really want, the method is out there.

Comment: It already is used. Visual C++ has modules now.

Answer (score 5):

My advice is to take the hit and rename the methods. It's a pain, but it'll make your code compliant and portable.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is good advice. "Always fix bugs before writing new code".

Comment: @Bathsheba I think its because the answer feels too comment-y

Comment: @PasserBy: Yes, that perception vexes me. Comments are for comments. Short and long answers should be placed in the answers section.

Answer (score 2):

There's no *legitimate* way if you get my meaning: `export` has been reserved since C++98 and has a curious history: until C++11 it was used with templates, and from and since C++11 it has no meaning but is still reserved. I imagine that `export` will gain a different meaning in a future standard that supports *modules*. **So if you want to write portable C++ you need to rename the methods**.

The behaviour on changing the behaviour of a reserved word using `#define` is *undefined*.

That said, MSVC2015 does not purport to be a C++11 compiler, and is lax about the fact that `export` is a keyword prior to that. So there is a case for legitimately using `#define` in your particular instance: your code is already not portable. You could check the value of `__cplusplus` so your code fails to compile with a C++11 compiler and onwards. That will buy you some time.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/export

Comment: IIrc, the value of `__cplusplus` is useless in MSVC. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I think they have sorted that in from VC2017.

Comment: Not sure about the C++11 bit, `export` has been a reserved keyword since c++98.

Comment: @MSalters: Hum. My understanding is that compilers prior to C++11 didn't have to support `export`, and it wasn't a keyword - rather like the `override` of C++11.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Microsoft very much didn't like it, but C++98 unconditionally requires `export`, and it was an ordinary keyword. C++98 didn't have "almost-keywords": as it was the first Standard there were no real backwards compatibility concerns.

Comment: @MSalters: That's interesting. No doubt the extra keywords they introduced in the cli stuff will bite them hard too.

Answer (score 1):

Formally it's Undefined Behavior, but VC2015 won't complain: `#define export EXPORT`. Or `/D` as a project setting.

Comment: There are 80+ projects to modify, and I'd really like to find something a bit less tedious. And the code needs to continue to work with the old compilers.

Comment: @JeffDege: You **absolutely** want to read about .vsprops (Property Sheets) then. As for older compilers - the main risk would be _newer_ compilers that _do_ give meaning to `export`.

Comment: @Bathsheba That sounds like a horrible job